# how to get particular server IP Address

Tags: jsp, servlets, ip-address

I wanna get a every user's server IP Address. I am using getIPAdress but it is giving me local IP address i need to get their server IP Address. Is there any method to get that.

Comment: request.getRemoteAddr(); a basic google is sufficient I guess

Answer (score 2):

its simple

```
String ipaddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

it will show local IP in your machine but in server, it will show the ISP's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Approach described in [this article](http://r.va.gg/2011/07/handling-x-forwarded-for-in-java-and-tomcat.html) should provide way more accurate determination of IP address also taking into account forwarding.